# Replace linked Google Form URL in HTML sidebar when copying the spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to update the link of my google Form in the HTML code of the spreadsheet's sidebar automatically when the spreadsheet is copied since the form is also copied and linked to the new spreadsheet. I cannot use the same Form for this application.

Script to display the sidebar

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("blablabla").addItem("blablabla", "showSidebar").addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Sidebar.html").setTitle("Remplir formulaire"));
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/xxxxxxxxxxxx" width="100%" height="595" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Chargement…</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm investigating to copy the URL from a random cell of the spreadsheet using the following script:

```
function GetUrlForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return ss.getFormUrl();
}
```

but i can't get anything out of this. I've explored the "window.location" but I am not good enough to know how to use it.

I am really new to programming and any help would be really appreciated. I can drastically change the code wothout any problem if needed.

Thank you kindly !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to update the src parameter of the iframe. I recommend you to add an id attribute to the iframe in your HTML to make it easier to reference.

```
<iframe id="myId" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/xxxxxxxxxxxx" width="100%" height="595" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Chargement…</iframe>
```

Then you can update the src parameter of the iframe after your retrieve the URL, this will automatically reload the frame.

```
function updateFrame(src){
  document.getElementById("myId").src = src; 
}
```

You can see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/src

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be more accurate, I would like the URL to update itself without any action on my end, when the spreadsheet is copied. It is likely it will get copied several time thus several google Form will be generated. The link in src= https://docs.google.com/forms/xxxxxxxxxxxx need to be modified automatically to be the URL of the spreadheet linked form. I don't know if am making any sense.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when the spreadsheet is copied"?

How is the spreadsheet copied. Also what do you mean by the form is also copied? 

Please describe the flow in more detail to better understand the requirement then.

Comment: The first spreadsheet with a linked form is a template. I want the HTML to be updated with the new form when i click "File" => "Make a copy".  After further researches, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Since you can only open forms by id and url, you might be better off creating a new form with your appscript when the sheet is copied using the Forms app